# Update JSON object data in AngularJS controller after editing the HTML using text-editor?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I need to edit an HTML page which binded with JSON object data using ng-bind. Here I didn't use ng-model. My code looks like

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/vPYSpOtA96b497iQMHrY?p=preview `
```

I used Kendo-editor for editing data. I can edit the data. But after editing I was unable to update the data to the controller. How can I update the edited data to the controller?

Comment: I don't see Controller used in HTML view. Can you add complete code. It'd be better if you create live code using StackSnippet.

Comment: In your controller you can access it by $scope.obj,a, after you update. Just console log see whether the value is changing.

Comment: i am not getting the updated data. in console i am getting the previous data only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all 
I got the answer for my question. Tinymce did a favour for me. By using UI-Tinymce i am able to update the json data